# Статистика по кандидатам выборов

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Хотелось бы увидеть статистику по кандидатам выборов. А именно:

- Количество голосов за/против
- Количество голосов за закрытие/переоткрытие и удаление/восстановление
- Количество правок закрытых вопросов, доля переоткрытия среди них
- Статистика по голосам в очередях проверок
- Количество полезных/спорных/отклонённых тревог

И т. д. - т. е. те данные, которые способны показать модель поведения кандидата.

Пытался потыкать DataSE, но что-то не разобрался, где там всё это хранится. Ну кроме первого пункта. https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/411661/525971/

---

Помощь для составляющих запрос:

На данный момент id кандидатов: `5079,14756,1984,17609,181472,15479,177221,182317,176610,178988,176051,178018`

Для того, чтобы добыть актуальный список, можно в консоли Хрома на [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1) выполнить скрипт:

```
Array.prototype.map.call($$(".post-signature.owner.candidate-score .user-details a"), a => a.href.match(/\d+/)[0]) + ''
```

Comment: Кстати, а за что минус? Неужели неинтересно статистику узнать? Или она у кого-то сильно отпугивающая?

Comment: Кстати, обновите список кандидатов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, `5079,14756,1984,17609,181472,15479,177221,182317,176610,178988,176051,178018` https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/411661

Comment: спасибо. Может все-таки доберусь и составлю общую табличку с открытой информацией.

Answer (score 4):

Важная информация, которую можно извлечь разумными способами, представлена на странице [Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics: Stack Overflow на русском 2015](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#ru.stackoverflow).

1. Эта страница включает голоса за и против (они, кстати, даже в профиле есть, причём в довольно подробной табличке).
2. Голоса за закрытие и открытие вне проверок — это приватная информация, она недоступна ни в профиле, ни на Data.SE.
3. Правки закрытых вопросов и переоткрытия — это любопытная статистика, теоретически можно вытащить из Data.SE, но придётся сильно попотеть, потому что придётся разбирать в SQL всю цепочку изменений и проверять порядок действий. Я пас.
4. Статистика по голосам в проверках частично доступна в самих проверках (точно помню, что при раскрытии блока с дополнительной информацией в очереди проверки предлагаемых правок отображается количество принятых и отклонённых правок для каждого голосовавшего). Из Data.SE эти данные получить не получится, там результаты голосования в проверках обезличены. Теоретически можно парсить профили, где часть (?) голосов видна...
5. Статистика по тревогам — это приватная информация, она доступна только ромбовым модераторам и выше.

Итого:

1. Уже доступно.
2. Приватная информация.
3. Сложный, но реализуемый запрос на Data.SE.
4. Недоступно на Data.SE.
5. Приватная информация.

Приватную информацию вы можете получить, только если кандидат сам того пожелает. Например, я предоставлял всем желающим мою статистику по тревогам, а в моей речи есть часть статистики по голосам.

В целом, кроме пункта 3 не вижу смысла собирать какую-то статистику. Оценить, как голосует кандидат, можно, посмотрев на последние несколько страниц проверок и на страницу активности в профиле.

---

<sub>P. S. Не нужно собирать статистику по тысячам проверок, чтобы понять, что вы без разбору голосуете за открытие всех вопросов, даже если они откровенно оффтопичны, а минусы практически никогда не ставите. Если в предложенной вами статистике я увижу желание не только открывать, но и улучшать вопросы, то я буду рад. Пока же я вижу 12 голосов "Оставить открытым" на вопросах типа "Посоветуйте фреймворк" на первой же странице и 0 правок за сегодня. Это показательно.
P. P. S. Ваше отношение к модерированию прекрасно видно и по первому взгляду на ваш профиль, и по вашей вступительной речи как кандидата. Да и "элайнмент" всех остальных кандидатов всем интересующимся хорошо известен. А большинство голосующих на все эти числа смотреть не будет, к сожалению.</sub>

Comment: не будьте так категоричны